# Windows Firewall notifies network uses after updating exe

Tags: windows, firewall

We have a software made in NWjs with auto-update. Recently we publish an update and some  clients report firewall notification after download this update.

[image: Windows Firewall Notification]

Now a need to know if is there a way to disable or avoid this notification show without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is perfectly normal, it authorize the app thru their firewalls.

Bypassing the firewall mean your update would check if the firewall rule exist, and if not add it before the application is runned.

In PowerShell see;

[Set-NetFirewallRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps)

For some API example, see like there;

[Creating a rule with the Windows Firewall API that applies to all applications run by a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809938/creating-a-rule-with-the-windows-firewall-api-that-applies-to-all-applications-r) or [Any way to turn the “internet off” in windows using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242566/any-way-to-turn-the-internet-off-in-windows-using-c) to see a C# example to create rule